# Как правильно оформлять сравнение в js?

Tags: javascript, архитектура, frontend

Часто сталкиваюсь при работе на фронте с такого рода сравнениями:

```
if(themes[i].type === "String" || themes[i].type === "Number" || themes[i].type === "Boolean" || themes[i].type === "Enumeration")
```

Чем больше типов добавляется, тем больше строка становится. С точки зрения правильного программирования и проектирования функций, как всё-таки идеально было бы написать?

Comment: `if (~array.indexOf(themes[i].type))`

Comment: `if (set.has(themes[i].type))` https://mdn.io/Set

Comment: `if (array.includes(themes[i].type))`

Comment: Можно же вынести все эти искомые значения в массив и использовать либо вариант Stranger in the Q, либо Rostyslav Kuzmovych

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych .includes работает везде кроме ie

Comment: @Lancelot и ето хорошо, уже так-то пора от него отказаться....

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych может наши внуки и увидят мир без ie)

Answer (score -1):

По моему правильнее писать в одну строку не более 70 символов(исходя из размера монитора), если не хватает места, то советую переводить строку...так будет правильнее, по эстетике и конечно же для удобства написания кода.

Comment: В какой-то ситуации это может и будет правильно, но в конкретном случае я применил .includes